# Sitecore URL Rewrite Module not working with query string

Tags: url-rewrite

I'm using the Sitecore URL Rewrite Module found here: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Url_Rewrite.aspx

The module allows you to create redirect items. The redirect items have the fields Path and Target. The Path field (Single-Line Text) specifies the path to redirect and the Target field (General Link) is the location to redirect to.

I've used the Target field to insert an internal link to the Home page with the query string `sc_lang=test`, but the query string is never appended to the redirect URL. Does anyone know, if this is an existing bug with the package?

I've also tried writing out the query string as `sc_lang=%3Dtest` but that did not work as well. I believe the query string is never being read from the link field in the package code, but I was curious, if anyone else had experienced this issue.

[image]

Comment: When you set up the redirect in the module did you append the querystring?
If so remove it. Also remove any trailing or leading slashes else it won't pick up the querystring correctly and redirect. The module matches on the url and should grab the querystring and forward on to the target url and append the querystring automatically. Thats how it's worked when I've used it anyway.

Comment: I am currently going through the nightmare of extending this module with custom conditions and actions (it is badly written and organized code), and I am quite sure that the query string parameter is not being read from the link at all. It only reads the anchor parameter.

Comment: @WulfgarDK I was pretty certain that was the case but it's nice to know someone else has seen the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamSeabridge you da man...

Comment: yeah it doesnt work with querystrings if you want querystrings just remove them like adam says it should relay them

Comment: No worries. I’ve spent a lot of time using the module so many hours have been sunk into working with it. Hope you get it sorted.